# Xcode hanging unit tests

Tags: xcode, testing, xctest

My unit tests for iOS app are hanging in the launching state. It is the same regardless launching on simulator or actual device. It looks like the test is launched and then app is stuck at the launch image forever without any sign of activity.
[image: Xcode shows testing but nothing happens]

Sometimes when I kill Xcode, the first unit test runs after re-launch OK but then it is the same story hanging all other tests :(

using Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: Is there something in the log output?

Comment: not a single line

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem

Comment: for me, it got solved after update to Xcode14

Answer (score 5):

Xcode 14.3.1 get the same issue,
What works for me is

Test Plan -> Edit Test Plan

[image]

and in Options
untick "Execute in parallel (if possible)"

[image]

Comment: Sadly, it is still an issue on Xcode 15.1, but your solution works!

Answer (score 1):

Before running your tests, try first deleting the app from your device.  Then from the XCode menu do Product -> Clean Build Folder,  Product -> Clean Test Results,  Product -> Build.  Next, change your Scheme to a Test Scheme.  Now you can click on the Test Navigator Icon (top left diamond shape icon).  And you can select the tests to run by clicking on the diamond icons next to each test, or by clicking the top-level one that runs all tests.

Comment: This worked for me.
I've done before all the steps described by you, except for "Clean Test Results", plus maybe the order of actions is also important. Thank you